# Why git push --force transfer blobs already included in remote

Tags: git

I have a question related to Git internals.

I have a remote git repo where each push on the master triggers a build.
In order to minimize the data transfer from my local repo to the remote one, I'm trying to use the following strategy:

1. The remote repo is never cloned (so no files are downloaded from remote to local)
2. Instead, a new local repository is inited and filled with all the local files that I want to transfer
3. Each time I want to trigger the build, a `git push --force` is performed

The forced push works, but it seems that **all** the local files are transferred to the remote repo, also immutable files having a big dimension that are **already included** in the remote blob store (i.e. in the objects folder, indexed by hash).

Is this the expected behaviour of Git ? Why files that are already in the remote blob store transferred ? I expected the Git **smart protocol** to avoid to retransfer something which is already in the remote blob store...

Comment: Your steps 1 and 2 are incredibly confusing.  How are you determining that the blobs are being transferred? Are you retaining the pack file and finding it inside of that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git avoids sending objects that the server already has by looking at the reachability of commits in the graph.  Git does not walk the entire history, looking at every tree and every blob and asking the remote if it has it.  This would be a very costly negotiation.

If you are pushing a new parentless commit each time then you are bypassing any system that can optimize the transfer.